# How different in the time complexity between these two code?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I am currently studying algorithms, and the **time difference** between these two codes is **more than 100 times.**

`input`

- The string's length is in range `1<= Length <= 1000000`

These two codes are part of the code used to solve an algorithm problem.

```cpp
string cutstring(string str, int i, int j) {
    string cup = "";
    for (int p = i; p <= j; p++) {
        cup += str[p];
    }
    return cup;
}

bool strComp(string str,int i,int j) {
    if (cutstring(str, i, j) == "IOI")
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

This code is faster than first code.

```cpp
bool strComp(string str,int i,int j) {
    if (str[i] == 'I' && str[i+1]=='O' && str[i+2] == 'I')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

I am wondering why there is such a significant time difference between these two codes
Any explanation would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, calling the function has some performance impact? Also measure having all optimization flags switched on.

Comment: Is `j` always `i+2`? Because otherwise these functions do not do the same thing. Also `i` better be less than `str.size()-2`.

Comment: j is alwyas i+2

Comment: Because the first implementation uses  *crazy expensive* operations like '+=' for no apparent reason (and is probably compiled without optimisations, which makes sure crazy expensive operations don't go anywhere and stay crazy expensive).

Comment: If `j` is always `i+2`, what's the reason for its existence?

Comment: 1000 times more time is same O(x). Even 10000000000 times slower would be same O(x)

Comment: Don't use `1` and `0` for booleans, use `true` and `false`. And `if (boolean_expression) return true; else return false;` --> `return boolean_expression;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are things that happen in the first code sample, that don't happen in the second, most notably:

- the string `str` gets copied to the argument of `cutstring` as it is passed by value (and thus must be copied). For large strings (up to length 1000000) this can be very time consuming, as new memory needs to be allocated and the whole string must be copied.
- the string `cup` in `cutstring` is created and expanded several times. On platforms that don't use small string optimization, this can lead to several memory (re)allocations.

I guess the first point is the most impactful. You can try to pass the string by reference (`string const& str` instead of `string str`) and see if that changes the times.

The second point is hard to remote diagnose, because you did not provide any information, about how you compile your code (which compiler and which compilation flags) and how you measure the timing. Generally this information is vital for performance/benchmark related questions.

And one last remark, if I might: Time complexity has nothing to do with all of this. As was pointed out in the comments to your question, a constant factor in between runtimes means the two algorithms have the same complexity. This is a perfect example, of why runtime complexity is more of theoretical interest, because to evaluate the actual performance of your code you must always measure.